# How to incorporate two (and) functions together in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to perform a formula in Excel 2010 stating if one cell reads "greens-spray" and another cell reads "M" then perform calculations for square footage. Or if one cell reads "greens-spray" and another cell reads "A" then perform calculations for acreage.

Kind of like this:

`=IF(AND($B$9="greens-spray",G20="M"),F20*(E9/1000),F20*200),or,=IF(AND($B$9="greens-spray",G20="A"),F26*(E9/43560),F26*4.591)`

Comment: `F20*(E9/1000)` is presumably your calculation for "square footage", but what's `F20*200`?

Comment: The first formula uses F20, the second one F26. Is that an error or should the OR branch use F26 instead of F20?

Comment: it is not a typo.  Does that cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The formula can only display one response, so your IF statements need to be nested within each other rather than an 'or' statement.

The usage for IF is:

`IF(condition,true,false)`

So if the first condition matches, we have an output in true. If it doesn't, we can go to the next condition test. Personally though, I'd do it slightly differently:

`IF($B$9="greens-spray",IF(G20="M",F20*(E9/1000),IF(G20="A",F26*(E9/43560),"M or A not specified!")),IF(G20="M",F20*200,IF(G20="A",F26*4.591,"M or A not specified!")))`

Or, indented:

```
IF($B$9="greens-spray",
    IF(G20="M",
        F20*(E9/1000),
        IF(G20="A",
            F26*(E9/43560),
            "M or A not specified!")),
    IF(G20="M",
        F20*200,
        IF(G20="A",
            F26*4.591,
            "M or A not specified!")))
```

Comment: With both new formulas we are missing the false portion each logical test.  Because if it say "greens Spray" and says "M" then perform this formula "F20*(E9/1000)". If it doesn't say "greens spray" but says "M" then perform this function"F20*200". Or it says "greens spray" and say "A" perform this function "F26*(E9/43560)".  If it doesn't say "greens spray" but says "A" then perform this function "F26*4.591".  Does that make it easier to understand?

Comment: @jeffcolo78 That makes more sense, yes. Will amend my answer shortly.

Comment: @jeffcolo78 amended, I fixed it on my phone though as I'm not at my computer, hopefully it should be right now but let me know if there's an error